# Overwriting features without first removing their layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers

I'm currently using `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` because I want to be able to play around with variables and not have to delete the file from my gdb every time. But whenever I rerun the script with a changed variable it runs fully but then my changes were not implemented even if I drag the feature back onto my map.

I found the only way to get it to overwrite is to delete the layer from the dataframe first (see image) then run script and then it appears with my changes.

[image]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap? Please present a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck when trying to overwrite your feature class.

Comment: Instead of overwriting the destination dataset directly, save the results to a temporary dataset.  Then truncate the destination dataset (ie, delete all of the features within it WITHOUT deleting the dataset itself).  Then copy (append) all of the features from the temporary dataset into the destination dataset.

Comment: I 2nd the comment by @SonofaBeach, process to IN_MEMORY then arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000036000000 in your existing feature class followed by arcpy.Append_management https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000 with schema type "NO_TEST" then the changes will be visible on the next update. You could also add RefreshActiveView https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000095000000 to the end of your script to refresh ArcMAP (not required for Pro).